# Solution to Multiple definition in C++

Tags: c++

guys, this is my first question in StackOverflow so forgive me if make any mistake.
I am writing a small project which contains 2 source files and 3 header files.

// some_template_functions.h

```
#ifndef SOME_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H
#define SOME_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H

template <typename T>
int getvalue(string line, string key, T & val)
{
    // method to get value (all the types except string) from line using key
}
template <>
int getvalue<string>(string line, string key, string &val)
{
    // method to get some string from line using key, similar to getvale<int>
    // but with slight difference to handle some special characters
}

#endif
```

//myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include "some_template_functions.h"

class MYCLASS
{
    //declarations of constructors, member functions and members
    double member_double;
    string member_string;
}

#endif
```

//myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

MYCLASS:MYCLASS()
{
    // for each member
    // using "getvalue" defined in "SOME_TEMPLATE_FUNCTION.H" to get the values 
    getvalue(line, key, member_double);
    getvalue(line, key, member_string);
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "some_template_functions.h"

int main()
{
    myclass A;
    int some_value;
    getvalue(line, key, value);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem compiling the main.o and myclass.o but it is just when I was trying to link the two object files I got error message like:

```
     myclass.cpp: multiple definition of int getvalue<std::basic_string><char, std::char_traits<char>, ...> and etc.    
     /tmp/cc22zEow.o:main.cpp: first defined here    
     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know the reason probably is because I am including "some_template_function.h" in both myclass.h and main.cpp, each myclass.o and main.o is going to have its own definition of getvalue which is causing the problem. If I change

```
#include "some_template_functions.h"
```

to

```
#ifndef SOME_TEMPLATE_FUNCTIONS_H
#define SOME_TEMPLATE_FUNCTIONS_H
#endif
```

the constructors of MYCLASS is not goint to work.

I plan to expand the "some_template_functions.h" and its .cpp file in the future so if possible I would like to keep them separated from the other files. And because the way I am declaring function "getvalue" my attempt to move its definition to .cpp file was not working out for me very well.

I've tried to solve this problem for days but since I just start to learn C++ so far I could not get this right. So please, any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: getvalue is defined multiple time here. The linker is not able to identify which function it should use. You can either overload the function to clearly distinguish the function to be called by the linker.

Comment: Interesting. Will the functions harbor statics? If not, slip an `inline` after the template param lists but before the return values. i.e. `template <typename T> inline int getvalue(string line, string key, T & val)`. But it vexes me none-the-less that your expansions aren't resolved.

Comment: @WhozCraig:"inline" actually works!!! Could you please explain a little bit more why? And I am not very familiar with the "statics", how will that work? Do I declare the getvalue as         `template <typename T> static int getvalue(string line, string key, T &val)`??

Comment: @Summet:Thank you for pointing out that. I know overloading definitely is an option but it is just this "template" that keeps bugging me. I will give it a try. BTW, is there any difference between using overloading and template in terms of performance?

Comment: @user3210923 Deitmar explained it below far better (and succinctly) than I could. Glad you found an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specialization of `getvalue<std::string>(...)` isn't a template and, thus, not implicitly `inline`. If you want to define this function in a header, e.g., because it is close to trivial and should be `inline`d, you'll need to mark it explicitly as `inline`. If the function does anything non-trivial it may be worth merely declaring the specialization in the header and defining it in a suitable translation unit.